# How can I set a Javascript variable in an HTML iFrame to the value of another variable from the parent?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a HTML file with bunch of javascript and an iFrame with the source stored on the same domain.

In the parent I have a variable:

```
var a = "sometext";
```

In the iFrame I want to do the following:

```
var b = window.parent.a;
alert(b);
```

This does not work (I just get an empty alert window) however, the following does work:

```
alert(window.parent.a);
```

Is there a reason why I cannot assign b to the value of a? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

index.html:

```
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var a = 'test';
  </script>
  <iframe src="page.html"/>
</html>
```

page.html:

```
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var b = window.parent.a;
    alert(b);
  </script>
</html>
```

Alert window contains "text".

However, if I set script in index.html before iframe, alert window contains "undefined":

```
<html>
  <iframe src="page.html"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var a = 'test';
  </script>
</html>
```

Maybe that's the case?